# Difference between ALTER ROLE WITH CREATEDB and GRANT CREATE ON TABLESPACE

Tags: postgresql

Coming from MySQL and not knowing about ROLEs I absentmindedly tried this

```
GRANT CREATE ON TABLESPACE pg_default TO username;
```

It didn't have the desired effect. The command that I was looking for was:

```
ALTER ROLE username WITH CREATEDB;
```

But what's the difference precisely? Does giving someone the CREATEDB role implicitly give them CREATE ON TABLESPACE ...? Is there a table where I can see all this?

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-grant.html), GRANT CREATE ON TABLESPACE means (my emphasis):

> For tablespaces, allows tables,
>   indexes, and temporary files to be
>   created within the tablespace, and
>   **allows databases to be
>   created** that have the
>   tablespace as their default
>   tablespace. (Note that revoking this
>   privilege will not alter the placement
>   of existing objects.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are completely different privileges.  CREATEDB means the role can create database.  If your role doesn't have that, it can't create databases, period.

Granting CREATE for a tablespace to a role means that the role will be able to use that tablespace as default tablespace for the database.  So a role that has CREATEDB will be able to create a database; just not on that tablespace.  Note that there's always a pg_default tablespace that will be used as default tablespace for databases that don't otherwise have a default tablespace.

Answer (score 2):

[Tablespaces](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/manage-ag-tablespaces.html) are not the same as [databases](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/manage-ag-overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the first statement gives you the ability to create tablespaces. This are physical files (or spaces on your storage device) that hold the data/indexes/... of the database.

So effectively you granted two different rights with the commands.